# NoSuchMessageException with Thymeleaf and SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im doing a SpringBoot application with thymeleaf, but I cant make the validator messages work. I have the messages on validation.propeties but I always get error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/app/person/addPerson.html]")] with root cause

org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'NotEmpty.personForm.name' for locale 'en_US'.
```

I tried to set the application to use a fixed language in configurations files, tried to create a validation_en_US.propeties.

validator.propeties:

```
NotEmpty=This field is required.
```

PersonValidador.java

```java
@Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        Person user = (Person) o;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name", "NotEmpty");
    }
```

PersonController.java

```java
@PostMapping("/app/addperson")
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("personForm") Person person, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        System.out.println(person.getName());
        personValidator.validate(person, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "app/person/addPerson";
        }
        return "app/person/listPerson";
    }
```

addPerson.html

```html
<form role="form" th:action="@{/app/addperson}"
                      th:object="${personForm}" method="POST">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input th:field="*{name}" th class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="" type="text">
                                    <ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}">
                                        <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('name')}" th:text="${err}">Input is incorrect</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/app/person/addPerson.html]")] with root cause

org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'NotEmpty.personForm.name' for locale 'en_US'.
```

I dont know what im doing wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: consider adding an answer to your own question and accepting it, in case others have the same problem as yourself.

Comment: @SadDay I have the same problem, how do you solved it?